# Changing the font color of JTextPane and continuing to write with the old one

Tags: java, swing

I have a problem with JTextPane font color and cannot seem to find a solution.
I have a text box (JTextPane) where the user is typing in text. At some point he presses a button which will change the color of some of the words.

```
SimpleAttributeSet attr = new SimpleAttributeSet();
StyleConstants.setBackground(attr, Color.RED);
StyledDocument doc = inputArea.getStyledDocument();
//find the start of the word
String wholeText = inputArea.getText();
int i = 0;
while (i <= wholeText.length() - word.length()) {
    if (wholeText.substring(i, i + word.length()).equals(word)) {
        doc.setCharacterAttributes(i, word.length(), attr, false);
    }
    i ++;
}
```

The problem now is that if this word is the last one from the text, if the user returns back to writing text, the newly typed text is red, not black. I have spent 2 hours trying to figure it out, but no luck.

Edit: I have also tried using Highlighter, but the problem is the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've use the following code before after inserting text with attributes into a document:

```
//  Newly typed text at the end of the document will inherit the
//  "keyword" attributes unless we remove the attributes

textPane.setCaretPosition(doc.getLength());
textPane.getInputAttributes().removeAttributes(keyWord);
```

Comment: What is the keyWord?

Comment: Ok, got it. It solves the problem partially, but I think I can manage from here.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I figured it out so I will post my solution.
Even with the above solution if I clicked the highlighted word and for example added a character to it, the caret would become red and won't be fixed by anything.

That is why I added a key listener to the text pane and on each key stroke I did this:

```
   inputArea.addKeyListener(new KeyListener() {
        @Override
        public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
            StyleConstants.setForeground(blackColor, Color.BLACK);

            inputArea.setCharacterAttributes(blackColor, false);

        }

        @Override
        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {

        }

        @Override
        public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {

        }
    });
```

Where black color is of type SimpleAttributeSet. This may be not very elegant, but solves it.